# Why is the local maximum distance between functions at the same point where their gradients are equal?

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, tangent-line

The distance between $f$ and $g$ is $d = f-g$. Then the local maximum distance(s) between the two functions is/are at the solution(s) of $d'(x)=f'(x)-g'(x)=0$. i.e. $f'(x)=g'(x)$, so where they have equal gradients.

I am struggling to find a clear/convincing way to explain why this is true using the graphs and the gradients (rate of change).

Comment: Assuming $f(x) > g(x)$ and that both are differentiable, if $f'(x) > g'(x)$, the two functions are getting farther, but if $f'(x) < g'(x)$, then the two functions are getting closer. The maximum distance occurs where you go from $f'(x) > g'(x)$ to $f'(x) < g'(x)$. This is how I'd look at it, intuitively at least.

Comment: @KM101: That's how understood it, and yet you said it in the way I needed it to be said to make sense! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!